# How To Set Display Style Property Using React useState Hook

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, firefox

I am trying to toggle the display property of an element
Although React doesn't throw an error, the browser does

## Below Is My React Code

```
import React ,{useState} from 'react'
import logo from './language.svg'
import './country.css'
const displayShow = "block !important"
const displayHide = "none !important"
function Country() {
    const [languageSelectDisplay, setlanguageSelectDisplay] = useState(displayHide)

    const toggleLanguageSelect = ()=>{
        return languageSelectDisplay === displayHide ? setlanguageSelectDisplay(displayShow) : setlanguageSelectDisplay(displayHide)

   return(
         <section className="language-options-container" id='language-options-container' 
         style={{display : languageSelectDisplay}}>
       <section />
)

    }
```

## Below Is The Error Firefox Is Throwing

```
Error in parsing value for ‘display’.  Declaration dropped.
```

Comment: Perhaps remove the importants?

Comment: I already tried yet it's still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using ternary which is the current correct way in react to hide an element :

```
{showLogin?<section className="language-options-container" id='language-options-container'/>:null}
```

```js
const mycomp = () => {
    const [showLogin, setShowLogin] = React.useState(false);
    
    const onClick = () => setShowLogin(!showLogin)
    
    return(<div id={"main"}>
{showLogin?<section className="language-options-container" id='language-options-container' />:null}</div>);

}

ReactDOM.render(<mycomp/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank Your For Your Logic.
I think it will be best if i go with it.

Comment: @codeanjero - just a question - has the ternary equation replaced this logic which was previously recommended for showing conditional content..... {showLogin && <section className="language-options-container" id='language-options-container' />...</section>}

Comment: @gavgrif
Infact i used conditiional rendering like {showLogin && 'whatever'} so no it hasn't replaced it